# How do I convert a height of an element given in vh to pixels?

Tags: javascript, css, height, viewport-units

I have the max-height of an element as 65vh. I need to convert it to pixels in my JavaScript to see whether an image can fit there or if I need to shrink/crop it.  (am doing win8 App development).

Will this work?

100 vh = `screen.height` therefore 65vh in pixels is `screen.height *0.65`

Comment: You are basically answering your own question. The real question here is: How can I find the height of the viewport?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Not necessarily `screen.height * 0.65`, but `viewport.height * 0.65`. Even though a Windows 8 app will always have the same height, regardless of the snapped state, this is an important difference in browser-based applications.

In JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.65;
```

If you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(window).height() * 0.65;
```

Comment: not accurate on mobile when you haven't scrolled down to shrink the address bar where 100vh is bigger than window height

Comment: For those trying to figure out what is viewport.height - document.documentElement.clientHeight (or clientWidth if you need).

Answer (score 0):

When I use `$("div").height();` it actually returns the value in pixels.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/U2z3Y/).